# Hosting local workbench in Angular SPFX application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, angularjs, workbench

Is it possible to run a local workbench like with regular SPFX React applications through the Sharepoint workbench? Currently when I try to run the ng serve command, it opens the application through localhost which is fine, but it doesn't have proper access to the Sharepoint list, so I can't test submitting items or reading items from the list. The localhost gives me a 403 Forbidden in Console, which I suspect is because its not hosted through Sharepoint and cant access the data properly.

Has anyone tried this? Is it even possible, or do I have to do some sort of work around? Alternatively I just have to test whatever I can on the localhost and then deploy the changes to the Dev Sharepoint site to see if the changes work in a proper production.

Comment: You have to use the SharePoint hosted workbench which you can access using the URL in this format: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`. Let me know if this works for you.